# Does GetAccessRules with both parameters set to false always return an empty AuthorizationRuleCollection in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, security, authorization

Does **'[GetAccessRules(false, false)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/System.Security.AccessControl.CommonObjectSecurity.GetAccessRules?view=net-7.0)'** always return an empty **'AuthorizationRuleCollection'**?

I have read the documentation, but I couldn't find any information regarding the scenario when both parameters are set to **'false'**.

```
FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(@"C:\test.txt");
if (!fileInfo.Exists)
{
    using (fileInfo.Create())
    {
    }
}
FileSecurity fileSecurity = fileInfo.GetAccessControl();
bool includeExplicit=false;
bool includeInherited=false;
Type targetType = typeof(SecurityIdentifier);
AuthorizationRuleCollection authorizationRuleCollection = fileSecurity.GetAccessRules(includeExplicit, includeInherited, targetType);
Console.WriteLine(authorizationRuleCollection.Count);  // Output: 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GetAccessRules` returns an empty AuthorizationRuleCollection no matter what.

To see this, we can look at the dotnet source code (links ahead). We see that the method in question `GetAccessRules` ([Source Code for GetAccessRules](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/security/accesscontrol/commonobjectsecurity.cs,8934713755f8d9ae)) calls `GetRules` ([Source Code for GetRules](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/security/accesscontrol/commonobjectsecurity.cs,1ef6853d86f1534a,references)). At the start of the `GetRules` method, it creates a new AuthorizationRuleCollection, that will be returned even if no rules get added to it.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @benjamin-Michaelis.

The `GetAccessRules` method retrieves a collection of access rules for a file along with an optional sub qualifier that matches the specified `SecurityIdentifier` objects. The false values for the `includeExplicit` and `includeInherited` parameters you see in the code block means that the method will not include access rules that are explicitly set for the file or inherited from a parent object, respectively.

Regarding the `AuthorizationRuleCollection`, it depends on the file's access rules. If `GetAccessRules` method is unable to retrieve any access rule, it returns an empty `AuthorizationRuleCollection`. Therefore, you have a guarantee that GetAccessRules(false, false) method will at least return an empty `AuthorizationRuleCollection` if it cannot find file's access rules.